# Json parsing with gson returns null object

Tags: android, json, gson

I am parsing a Json string via gson , this is the Json string

```
[
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Australia",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Kiev",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "South Africa",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "Stockholm",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 6,
    "Name": "Paris",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 7,
    "Name": "Moscow",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 8,
    "Name": "New York City",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 9,
    "Name": "Germany",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 10,
    "Name": "Copenhagen",
    "Active": true
},
{
    "ID": 11,
    "Name": "Amsterdam",
    "Active": true
}
]
```

and this is the Object which is going to be useed

```
public class MyBranch extends Entity {

public MyBranch () {
    super();
}

public MyBranch (int id, String name, String isActive) {
    super();
    _ID = id;
    _Name = name;
    _Active = isActive;
}

@Column(name = "id", primaryKey = true)
public int _ID;
public String _Name;
public String _Active;

}
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type t = new TypeToken<List<MyBranch >>() {}.getType();     
List<MyBranch > list = (List<MyBranch >) gson.fromJson(json, t);
```

the list constructed and it has 10 object , but the problem is all of object's data members is null, i dont no what's wrong with this. The Entity is OrmDroid's Entity class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Names of the fields in your `MyBranch` class don't match to the fields in your `json` so you have to use `SerializedName` annotation.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyBranch extends Entity {
    public MyBranch () {
        super();
    }

    public MyBranch (int id, String name, String isActive) {
        super();
        _ID = id;
        _Name = name;
        _Active = isActive;
    }

    @Column(name = "id", primaryKey = true)
    @SerializedName("ID")
    public int _ID;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String _Name;

    @SerializedName("Active")
    public String _Active;
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can also avoid using `SerializedName` annotation by simple renaming `MyBranch` fields:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyBranch extends Entity {
    public MyBranch () {
        super();
    }

    public MyBranch (int id, String name, String isActive) {
        super();
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Active = isActive;
    }

    @Column(name = "id", primaryKey = true)
    public int ID;
    public String Name;
    public String Active;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `List` use `ArrayList` ?

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type t = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyBranch >>() {}.getType();     
ArrayList<MyBranch > list = (ArrayList<MyBranch >) gson.fromJson(json, t);
```

Comment: Yeah... the problem is that you do not use the `@SerializedName` and the variable names are different than the JSON tags, see @vmironov post.